# Phaser .js memory leak. how properly release objects within Phaser Canvas app?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

We have a game running Phaser .JS.
Whilie using browsers, seems that the memory keeps growing.

What is the proper method cleaning the objects?

Comment: What version? Phaser 2 or 3?

Comment: Phaser CE 2.10.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will condense my answer to make it usable.

Phaser 2 claims that most objects can be simply dereferenced by assigning null to their references and this **should** trigger garbage collection.

Instead others, like TilemapLayers, will explicitly need specific their destructors to be invoked.

Others like Particle can be optionally destroyed (e.g. `Particle.kill()`).

However as you have found out, the automatic garbage collector isn't always good and especially if you keep the browser open for a long time, it leaks memory.

So you should kill, stop, remove and destroy everything, **even optional objects**. Even if you don't find a specific destructor, most objects inherit from PIXI.DisplayObject and therefore implement `.RemoveChild` and variants. Especially the parent `Phaser.Stage`

Go here: https://phaser.io/learn/chains

Search these: `destroy` `removeAll` `.stage.remove` (and `remove` with all its prefixes and suffixes including removeChild and variants) `stop` `kill`.

If you don't find a specific destructor, remember the PIXI.DisplayObject inheritance and removeChild/ren.

Also remember to invoke `Stage.removeStageReference()` when you quit.

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In Phaser 3 (I don't know Phaser2) it is not sufficient to remove a child GameObject. Unless you also call its destroy() method, it will consume memory.